# res.send data from async function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, vue.js, get

My server.js file serves an array of objects that are created in a function called doScrape.  I can console log them out (see code below), but the scrapedData takes a while to be created and I think this is why the res.send sends an object that is not intelligible.  Do I need to somehow delay the res.send(scrapedData) command?

```
app.get('/dash/jobads', function(req, res, next){
  var scrapedData = doScrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  });
  res.send(scrapedData)
  console.log('This is data from /dash/jobads:', scrapedData)
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot return anything from an asynchronous function. Put the `res.send()` line *inside* the `then()` callback function instead.

Comment: This worked great - thank you!